# Como extrair a face de um documento de RG de uma image escaneada

Tags: opencv

Ola, Pessoal

Estou desenvolvendo uma solução onde uso Google Cloud Vision para analisar textos na imagem, isso já esta pronto em minha solução. Mando a imagem e o Google Vision me retorna as palavras encontradas e suas coordenadas.

O que eu necessito é extrair a face (parte de traz do documento de RG) da imagem escaneada, fiz vários testes com OpenCV, EmguCV (C#) e tentei usar TensorFlow (Google) usando rede neural para tentar criar algo que reconheça a face do documento de RG, mas tudo e meio confuso nesta parte pois existe pouco conteúdo referente a OpenCV, EmguCV e TensorFlow e o pouco conteúdo que existe são todos em inglês ou em outras linguás.

O TensorFlow utiliza para treinar Python (não sei também se vale a pena) pois exite uma serie de fatores para utilizar o TensorFlow instalação, configuração levando em conta o tempo de meu aprendizado sem saber se isso dará certo para meu projeto.

OpenCV eu queria usa-la mas ainda esta obscuro a forma de como é  treinado os modelo também e em python ou C++ meus conhecimentos nestas linguagens são escassos mas sou sênior modestamente falando em C# mas não sei direito em que caminho seguir para isso.

Hoje eu envio a imagem do jeito que recebo para api do Google Vision e resgato as informações da analise OCR resumindo eu quero detectar o RG dentro da imagem escaneada e estrai-lo  rotacionar-lo para deixa-lo na horizontal e ai sim envia-lo para a api Google Vision.

Alguém tem alguma ideia para fazer esse "passo antes de enviar" que seja mediano ou algum modelo de fácil entendimento de como treinar modelos de imagens pelo OpenCV. Eu andei lendo bastante e o que teoricamente preciso e o modelo de rede neural Convolucional Neural Network, para Detect Object.

Fiz vários exemplos de demarcar na imagem usando OpenCV (EmguCV) mas devido talvez a falta de conhecimento da framework nao consegui utilizei e já li vários tutoriais para deixar a imagem e GrayScale e Threshold(limiar ou binarizada), já usei a biblioteca AForge mas mesmo assim não consegui chegar num estagio ou nível legal do projeto necessito deste passo antes de enviar para analise OCR.

Peço dicas opnioes e exemplos se alguém tiver.

Abraços.

Comment: Você colocou várias perguntas em uma só. Melhor separar.  Qual é o seu principal objetivo? Pegar uma imagem de RG e selecionar com um retângulo onde fica a foto?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o Opencv com várias técnicas e filtros, como edge/canny (efeito de filme de fotografia), na sequência utilizar a técnica boundary para definir a borda do documento, caso a borda esteja quebrada você utilizará a técnica de operação morfológica de dilatação para engrossar a borda de modo a aproximar os encontros entre linhas e usar os recursos do contornos para aplicar os cálculos geométricos e com o resultado estacionar a imagem.